# Google search company info box

Tags: google-search

What controls this section https://www.screencast.com/t/VZFEsA7TbD in Google results?

Is it collected by Google from the website schema.org code?

I have verified my  business but do not see how I can add more info to the box.
I can only suggest that some existing info needs to be changed: https://www.screencast.com/t/4Fslkpku